# Profile creation and form submission in Android

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android and trying hard to get on to it. I have searched a lot to find a better and reliable way to do what I want in my application. But didnt get lucky to find specific information. Can anybody tell me how to create a simple login page including form submission text input fields like name , address, age , sex and password and retype password etc. I want to have a "Create Profile" link on the Emulator Home Screen. Once the user clicked on it will direct the user to the profile creation page. I want to create login IDs or profiles many as I want, submit the form to my emulator, store them in a database and retrieve the information in a new page named "Profile Home page" by providing the password. So in a way when the user click on the Submit Form button then immediately a window will appear to type and enter the password. If the password is right then the "Profile Home page" will appear. Ofcourse the user should be able to edit their personal information. Is there any kind buddy who can help me out this? Any suggestion, ideas or clues are highly appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for an entire app. I think first you need to learn and get basic idea about how to work with android widgets. Because what you have asked here is totally big and no one will be ready to provide you with an answer as it might become clumsy. So better start your task in simple steps and then ask for doubts in it. Not your whole task though! Sorry to say this.

Answer (score 0):

@Pervanee All you need to do is create simple activities and switch them based on the events. As andro said whatever you are asking for is a full application so break it down into screens and then find out how you can create each one. Plenty of code for what you ask will be there if you do some search. :)

Comment: @nitin..Thanks for your effort. can you point me to some relative documents?

Comment: This should be all you need to get started www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android2MyFirstApplication.html